# How to rearrange or remove contents under #BODY# in oracle apex

Tags: apex, oracle-apex-5.1

So basically I'm new to oracle apex, i have created a blank page in an  mobile application in apex and then created a static region having a select list.

Noticed that the select list item is to the right of the screen, i know i can use css to move it to the required spot, but when I did a page inspection, noticed that #BODY# had other divs as well and wanted to know whether the divs or spans under #BODY# can be edited, if so from where and how?

Comment: What is a "drop down menu"? I can imagine how it looks like, but - Is it a *Select List" item, actually?

Comment: Yes Select Item list is the technical name  :) anyways hoping you got the gist and are able to provide a solution? :)

Comment: Thank you for the info; I replied to your question, have a look. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK then, a Select List item it is.

- Select it
- in its properties (on the right hand side of the screen), you'll see the **Layout** section
- in there, there are some properties you might find interesting

  - column - set to "Automatic" by default, and yes - it positions the item "right" on the screen (I don't know why Apex authors decided to do it that way; I'd be happier if it was "left"), somewhere to the 4th of 5th column. What does that column mean? When you run the page, there's the bottom toolbar available to developers. In version 5.x, there's the option (I can't remember its name; most probably it is "Show layout columns") which enables you to show the *grid* - you'll see vertical "lines" (columns) and see where's each of your items positioned. On Apex 18.1 (available at apex.oracle.com), you'd click "Page info" and select "Show layout columns".

    - so, if you want to move it left, set the "Column" property to 1 (1st column on the screen)
  - modifying the "Column" property might require adjusting two additional properties: "Column span" and "Label column span".

I suggest you try to set those properties to different values and see what happens. Apex will inform you if you set something irregular.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for a desktop application. I forgot to mention mine was a mobile application in oracle apex. Sorry about that, have edited the question